# Case-insensitive Regular Expression - VBA

Tags: arrays, regex, excel, vba

<sub>***Background:***</sub>

Just now, I was answering a question and was playing around with `RegEx` within `VBA`. The goal is to create a list of names that exist within a string. `RegEx` was the go-to solution since we want to prevent `VBA` to stumble over punctuation marks and substrings that look similar e.g.: `Jack` or `Jacky`.

---

<sub>***Sample Data:***</sub>

Let me give a simple sample. Imagine we have a string like:

```
Dim str As String: str = "Jack's turn, Becky's or Frank?"
```

we want to know which names in a certain array are mentioned within the string, for example:

```
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Jack", "Frank")
```

---

<sub>***Sample Code:***</sub>

To prevent an iteration over the array, I went with the following code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "Jack's turn, Becky's or Frank?"
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Jack", "Frank", "Beth")
Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

regex.Pattern = "\b(" & Join(arr, "|") & ")\b"
regex.Global = True

Set hits = regex.Execute(str)
For Each hit In hits
    Debug.Print hit
Next hit

End Sub
```

---

<sub>***Problem:***</sub>

Whereas the above would neatly return the two hits, it would not work case-insensitive. For example, changing the following line will only return `Jack`:

```
Dim str As String: str = "Jack's turn, Becky's or frank?"
```

I thought I could counter that by turning off case-sensitivity using `(?i)`:

```
regex.Pattern = "(?i)\b(" & Join(arr, "|") & ")\b"
```

But the problem is that this would work perfectly for most languages ([test here](https://regex101.com/r/Cq0P39/2)), however `VBA` seems to have a problem with it and generates an `Error 5017` upon execution.

---

<sub>***Question:***</sub>

Does anybody know why? Is this not supported within `VBA` or is my syntax wrong? If not supported, what is the alternative to get hits case-insensitive while retaining the possibility to `Join` the array of names?

<sub>***Bonus-Question:***</sub>

Ultimately I would like to `Join` the `Hits` together through a delimiter, for example like:

```
Debug.Print Join(regex.Execute(str),", ")
```

However, I realized execution returns a collection and needs iteration first which I would like to avoid.

Comment: regex.ignorecase = True  ? Set the property on the object.

Comment: @QHarr, so simple. That's great. I guess that's `VBA` alternative to `(?i)`? Care to put it down in an answer?

Comment: I don't know enough about vba regex. For the purposes of flexibility it would be nice if there is a way to pass it in the pattern though I guess if you create a function you could pass a true false param to set this property at same time as assign pattern

Comment: Would be great if someone still could explain why the pattern itself would return an error for `VBA`. Also, @QHarr, any idea on the `Join` without iteration?

Comment: I don't think it is supported from a quick read of syntax section in documentation.

Comment: It's all good @Qharr, those links have been helpfull to me. Thanks for thinking along =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the property on the RegExp object i.e.

```
regex.ignorecase = True
```

[RegExp object](https://bytecomb.com/regular-expressions-in-vba/)

> The RegExp object has three properties that affect how regular
> expressions are applied:
>
> IgnoreCase: I trust this is self-explanatory
>
> Global: Determines
> whether or not to find all possible matches in the input string. If
> Global is set to false, only the first match will be found or
> replaced, as applicable.
>
> MultiLine: Determines whether matches can
> span accross line breaks.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//1400241x%28v%3dvs.85%29

And from https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html regarding VBScript’s Regular Expression Support as we are using Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

> No mode modifiers to set matching options within the regular expression.